# Get returned value of interface method

Tags: java, android, callback, return-value

I have implemented this interface:

```
public interface Callback {
    public abstract ArrayList<String> done(ArrayList<Document> docs);
}
```

Also this method:

```
 public void getNearUsers(Callback callback, LatLng loc) {
        new GetNearUsersASyncTask(callback, loc).execute();
    }
    public class GetNearUsersASyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Document>>{
        Callback callback;
        LatLng loc;
        ArrayList<Document> documents;

        public GetNearUsersASyncTask(Callback callback, LatLng loc){
            this.callback=callback;
            this.loc=loc;
            documents = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Document> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ...

            return documents;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Document> docs) {
            ...
            callback.done(docs);
            super.onPostExecute(docs);
        }
    }
```

And finally this one:

```
    public ArrayList<String> gotoRec() {
        final ArrayList<String> finalPostIDs = new ArrayList<>();
                serverRequest.getNearUsers(new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public ArrayList<String> done(ArrayList<Document> users){               
                        ...
                        return finalPostIDs;
                    }
                }, loc);

            }
        });
        //return the finalPostIDs of override method;
    }
```

My question is this:

How can i have the finalPostIDs returned ArrayList of Callback interface to return it in gotoRec method ? Is there a way or should i take another road ?

Comment: Not possible. AsyncTask is asynchronous so you can't force method to wait for its result and then return the value - it would remove the point of async.

Comment: Ok thats what i thought too i was just wondering if there is a 'magic' way : p Thanks for your response!

Comment: So there is no way to retrieve finalPostIDs outside getNearUsers right?

Comment: Well I don't really see the point of that Callback interface at all. Why don't you just pass in some object reference to AsyncTask contructor and then invoke its public method from onPostExecute? You can just move logic inside done() method to onPostExecute.

Comment: Ok i see what you'r saying. I'll try it this way

Comment: Ok my problem solved i did what i had to do by following your suggestion. Thanks Wukash